# How to Render @Html.Sitecore().Field using custom Model Item in Sitecore MVC

Tags: experience-editor, razor

I have a model `ArticleItem` which has some fields that I populate with some Business Logic.

Now on the view where I return `ArticleItem` I want to render a RTE content so that it is Page Editor friendly

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Article Body", @Model.ArticleItem)
```

is not working.

Does it only works with `Sitecore.Items.Item`?

If I want to use a custom Model instead how can I render RTE so it is Page Editor mode friendly?

I cannot use the context item in this case as I am rendering from a multilist inside the Context Item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@Html.Sitecore().Field` only works with real items and it sounds like `Model.ArticleItem` is not a real Sitecore Item.

What you want to do is render the Sitecore field as HTML in your model and render  that.

```
// get your sitecore item
var item = RenderingContext.Current.ContextItem;

// get the sitecore editor html (will only render the data if not in edit mode) 
var fieldHtml = SC.Web.UI.WebControls.FieldRenderer.Render(item, "title");

// bind the fieldHtml to a HtmlString field on your model
MyModel.TitleField = fieldHtml


public class MyModel
{
    public HtmlString TitleField { get; set; }
}
```

Now in you view you can just render the model's `TitleField` property and you will get the RTE editor you want in page.

```
<div>@Model.TitleField</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! this work.
What do I do for Images and MultList/TreeList any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

In your controller (or service), you could also add the `Sitecore.Items.Item` on the view model that you send to your view and then use that item to render the content and Experience Editor functionality:

## Controller/service

```
var contextItem = RenderingContext.Current.ContextItem;

var articleItem = // get article item from multilist on contextItem;

var viewModel = new ArticleViewModel
                    {
                        /// ... other business fields ...
                        ArticleItem = articleItem;
                    };
```

## View

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Article Body", @Model.ArticleItem)
```

Comment: this is what I am doing currently but it does not work because apparently it works only with Sitecore Item and not Model Item unless handled with FieldRender.Render

Comment: Yes, that's right; `articleItem` will need to be the actual `Sitecore.Items.Item`.

Answer (score -2):

Views.cshtml:

```
<div>
  @Html.Sitecore().field(@Model.Article)
</div>
```

in Model.cs

```
public string Article
        {
            get { return Templates.Models.Articles.Article;}
        }
```

Comment: this does not work.